# Meaning of "way before"

Tags: phrase-meaning

At about 53s of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwDq4adJwzM&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtNlUrzyH5r6jN9ulIgZBpdo&index=11), I listened a phrase "way before". Did I hear it in a wrong way or it has some meaning?

Searched and got [this result](http://www.urbandictionary.com/tags.php?tag=way+before). But it seems the page is explaining `since '86`.

Comment: *Way* here is a colloquial adverb meaning approximately "at a great distance, long". See [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/way), "adverb".

Comment: It would be better to post the sentence rather than making us listen to the video. |I get it now.| = better in this context.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't provide the text when I first posted this question because I thought I may listen wrong. But now I think it could be helpful to provide more text details as you said. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The need to program machines existed **way before** the development of computers

As StoneyB says, "way" here is a *colloquial* use that means "long".  In other contexts it can mean "much" or "very" -- basically, it is used to add emphasis to whatever comes after it.

> I want to be a programmer, but it's **way too technical** for me.
>
> All this programming stuff is **way over my head**.
>
> My car is parked **way out** on the other side of the parking lot.

The speaker can add extra emphasis by elongating "way":

> Dude, you need to chill.  You're being **waaaaaay too serious** right now.